# Using Express with GET request in server

Tags: node.js, express

Here below there are tow get requests i have defined and hard coded

They fetch data from the server and results JSON

is there a way to combine the two get requests into one, i mean to generate JSON on the fly with just one get request ..... which generates an output depending on the i?p it receives from client

---

**My Express program ::**

```
var express = require('express')
  , async = require('async')
  , http = require('http')
  , mysql = require('mysql'); 

var app = express();

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'xxx',
    password: "xxx",
    database: 'collages'
});

connection.connect(); 

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 7002);

//
//REQUEST FOR FIRST REQUEST
//

app.get('/',function(request,response){
    var name_of_Collages, RestaurantTimings;

    async.series( [
        // Get the first table contents
        function ( callback ) {
            connection.query('SELECT * FROM restaurants', function(err, rows, fields)
                {
                        console.log('Connection result error '+err);
                        name_of_Collages = rows;
                        callback();
                });
        },
        // Get the second table contents
        function ( callback ) {
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM RestaurantTimings', function(err, rows, fields)

            {
                    console.log('Connection result error '+err);
                    RestaurantTimings = rows;
                    callback();
            });
        }

   // Send the response
], function ( error, results ) {
    response.json({
        'Collages' : name_of_Collages,
        'RestaurantTimings' : RestaurantTimings
    });
} );

} );



//
//REQUEST FOR Collage SCREEN
//


app.get('/College1',function(request,response){
    var College1, RestaurantTimings;

    async.series( [
        // Get the first table contents
        function ( callback ) {
            connection.query('SELECT * FROM College1', function(err, rows, fields)
                {
                        console.log('Connection result error '+err);
                        College1 = rows;
                        callback();
                });
        },
        // Get the second table contents
        function ( callback ) {
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM RestaurantTimings', function(err, rows, fields)

            {
                    console.log('Connection result error '+err);
                    RestaurantTimings = rows;
                    callback();
            });
        }

   // Send the response
], function ( error, results ) {
    response.json({
        'College' : College1,
        'RestaurantTimings' : RestaurantTimings
    });
} );


} );



http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

### [AFTER - EDIT]

Now i have a express program as above :: What it does ? -> it sends a JSON back to client

i have defined two get requests ::

Case 1> :: If i use `http:// 40.2.3.3:8213/` I get a JSON response , from data obtained from Mysql say `table1` - > table1 is a list of colleges

case 2> :: If i use `http:// 40.2.3.3:8213/College1` I get another JSON response, from data obtained from Mysql say `table2` -> table two is description of college1

**I deploy my complete application in the server end**

- Now tomorrow i add a new value to `table1` -> a new college name and define it in mysql datbase
- Next i add a new database table for new college2 also in mysql database

**I should not modify the express code to get the new JSON ::**

- If the client asks for the college2 information ..... the express
  program should take that input and generate the JSON on FLY !!

**Hope i am clear**

*Thanks,*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically, if I understand your question right, you want the data for the /College1 request to be ready (or you want to start prefetching it) after the first request.

You can always trigger an asynchronous function to start computing this data after writing and ending the response in your first request. You can save this data in a cache layer (like redis). In your second function, you can fetch the data from Redis (if the data is not yet available, try again in a second or so). This will help if your second query is a intensive one and takes up quite a bit of time. If this is not the case, doing all this will probably just add a little latency.
You can always use an object in your node program to keep a track of this too, but it isn't recommended as you will have to start managing the memory and cleanup yourself which will be a headache. It also means that your node application won't scale out nicely.

Edit:  just saw your edit. Your problem is not a Node.js or express problem. If you are going to make new tables when new data needs to be entered in system, you need to rethink your database design. You have a table which will have all college entries, with a college_id column to tell which entries belong to which college. And you should route requests like /college/?id=1

Comment: Thanks for the i/p ..... I was refering :: how to make a single get request which generates different JSON response depending on i/p ..... im not refering to like switch case etc which again requires hard coding .... say i define a express server today ... how to make it stand regardless of no to entries increase in the database of back of express with no changes to be made to server code

Comment: @Sky oh.. you really didn't explain it properly at all the first time. Also, you don't mean I/P. You mean request URL. Anyway, have a look at my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `app.all` instead of `app.get`:

```
app.all('/:command?',function(request,response){
    var command = users[req.params.command];
```

This should then allow you to add some `if` conditions to your request (set into the `command` variable) to merge those two into one.

Comment: Thanks for the i/p ..... I was refering :: how to make a single get request which generates different JSON response depending on i/p ..... im not refering to like switch case etc which again requires hard coding .... say i define a express server today ... how to make it stand regardless of no to entries increase in the database of back of express with no changes to be made to server code .... will your i/p can i use for that case ?

Comment: Sorry, so you want a different response depending on what IP Address the initial request comes from? Can I ask for a bit more information on what you are trying to do? It doesn't sound like this is a reliable method of switching results.

Comment: Please look at the updated question ..... I have tried to explain my scenario ... I am a newbie to express so im trying my best to explain in technically .... please give a feedback on my edited question by pointing me to right direction .... like any links or concepts i need to look for to achieve this !

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameters to your code using query string in the get like that:

`domain.com?param=value&param2=value2`

Then in the get callbacks you defined you can use those params to manipulate the response

to get the params in the callback just use that:

```
var firstParam = request.query.param;
var secondParam = request.query.param2;
```

Comment: Thanks for the i/p ..... I was refering :: how to make a single get request which generates different JSON response depending on i/p ..... im not refering to like switch case etc which again requires hard coding .... say i define a express server today ... how to make it stand regardless of no to entries increase in the database of back of express with no changes to be made to server code .... will your i/p can i use for that case ?